# Firebase Swift: Converting Snapshots to Dictionary

Tags: swift, firebase

I have the following snapshots and I'm trying to create an array of dictionary. I have been fiddling ways to cast as [String: Bool] or getting snapshot.value or whatsoever but can't seem to work correctly. Any advice how can I go about doing it?

```
ref.child("activities").child(userUID!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
       print(snapshot)
}) { (error) in
       print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The snapshots looks like this:

> Snap (Person1) 0
>
> Snap (Person2) 0
>
> Snap (Person3) 0

I am trying to write an array like this:

```
Optional(["Person3": false, "Person2": false, "Person1": false])
```

Some advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the snapshots value as [String:Bool]. You can do it with the code below.

```
snapshot.value as? [String:Bool]
```

Edit:
You say it doesn't work...are you sure that you have any data to retrieve?

If you do like this you'll find out if you have any data.

```
if let value = snapshot.value{
    //there is data available
    let data = value as [string:Any]
    print("\(data)")
}else{
    //there is no data available. snapshot.value is nil
    print("No data available from snapshot.value!!!!")
}
```

Comment: Hi @joakim Doesn't really work. optional casting returns nil and force casting returns an error Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x103e8a5b8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x103e8b288).